# Showing the list of array items using condition in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I created an application where the user can change the todo status and also to filter the todos.

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const todos = [
    {
      title: "test",
      id: 1,
      done: false
    },
    {
      title: "test2",
      id: 2,
      done: true
    }
  ];
  const [myTodo, setMyTodo] = useState(todos);

  const changeStatus = (e, id) => {
    console.log(e.target.value, id);
    const newValues = todos.map((i) => {
      if (id === i.id) {
        return {
          ...i,
          done: e.target.value === "false" ? true : false
        };
      }
      return i;
    });
    setMyTodo(newValues);
  };

  const filterDone = () => {
    const r = myTodo.filter((i) => i.done === true);
    setMyTodo(r);
  };

  const filterActive = () => {
    const r = myTodo.filter((i) => i.done === false);
    setMyTodo(r);
  };

  const filterAll = () => {
    setMyTodo(myTodo);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={filterAll}>Filter By all</button>
      <button onClick={filterDone}>Filter By donne</button>
      <button onClick={filterActive}>Filter By active</button>

      {myTodo.map((t) => {
        return (
          <div>
            {t.title}
            <select onChange={(e) => changeStatus(e, t.id)} name="status">
              <option hidden>status</option>
              <option value="false">Done</option>
              <option value="true">Active</option>
            </select>
            {t.done ? "done" : "active"}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now when i try to filter i don't get the expected result. Clicking multiple times on different buttons i don't get anything as results. How to change the code to be able to filter trought the list of todos taking into account that the user can change the status of each todo?
demo:https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-thunder-jywy6?file=/src/App.js:0-1506

Answer (score 0):

When you set the new state with the filtered information, your original data is gone, deleted basically. Instead you should filter the data only where you need it filtered, without setting any new state. That way the todos in the view are filtered but you still have all the todos in state.

```
export default function App() {
  const todos = [
    {
      title: "test",
      id: 1,
      done: false
    },
    {
      title: "test2",
      id: 2,
      done: true
    }
  ];
  const [myTodo, setMyTodo] = useState(todos);
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState(null);
 
  ...

  const filterDone = () => {
    setFilter("done");
  };

  const filterActive = () => {
    setFilter("active");
  };

  const filterAll = () => {
    setFilter(null);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={filterAll}>Filter By all</button>
      <button onClick={filterDone}>Filter By donne</button>
      <button onClick={filterActive}>Filter By active</button>

      {myTodo
        .filter((t) => {
          if (filter === "done") return t.done === true;
          if (filter === "active") return t.done === false;
          return true;
        })
        .map((t) => {
          return (
            <div>
              {t.title}
              <select onChange={(e) => changeStatus(e, t.id)} name="status">
                <option hidden>status</option>
                <option value="false">Done</option>
                <option value="true">Active</option>
              </select>
              {t.done ? "done" : "active"}
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-pond-3qmsq?file=/src/App.js